# Finding ID based on first and last name

Tags: excel, lookup, excel-2013, vba

I have a list that contains Employee ID in Col A, First Name in Col B, Last Name in Col C. I am needing to write a macro that gives a userform to input First and Last Name and from there it will put the proper Employee ID into the first unused cell in Col E and then loop back to the userform.

I already know how to build the Userform and will have two buttons on it one that reads "Next" and one that reads "End". The "Next" button will loop the Userform and the "End" will just close the Userform.

Plan on leaving the Userform named Userform1 and naming the input boxes as "FirstName" and "LastName". So I know that to reference these from the macro I would call for Userform1.FirstName.Value or Userform1.LastName.Value depending on which part I need at the moment.

The part I am not sure on is how to the matching of two variables and then looking to the left for the ID. I can move the ID Col to be after the name Cols if that helps but I am still not sure how to write so that both names must match.

As for error trapping I planned on having a MsgBox state "There are no matching entries." If the person does not exist in the list. However I am unsure of how to handle the super unlikely but possible situation of if two people on the list have the same name. So any suggestions for this would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for the next button

```
Private Sub NextButton_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim matchFound As Boolean
Dim matchCount As Long
Dim matchRow As Long
Dim i As Long

'Determine the first empty cell in column E
If Cells(1, 5).Value = "" Then
    emptyRow = 1
Else
    emptyRow = Cells(Columns(5).Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End If

matchFound = False
matchCount = 0
matchRow = 0

'Loop through all of rows that have an employee id
For i = 1 To Cells(Columns(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If (UCase(FirstName.Value) = UCase(Cells(i, 2).Value)) And (UCase(LastName.Value) = UCase(Cells(i, 3).Value)) Then
        matchCount = matchCount + 1
        matchRow = i
        matchFound = True
    End If
Next

'Alert user of any errors
If matchFound = False Then
    MsgBox ("There are no matching entries")
ElseIf matchCount > 1 Then
    MsgBox ("There were multiple matches")
Else
'If there are no errors add employee id to the list
    Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = Cells(matchRow, 1).Value
    emptyRow = emptyRow + 1
End If

'Clear the userform
FirstName.Text = ""
LastName.Text = ""

End Sub
```

I'm not sure what the best course of action to take if there are multiple matches, so for now I just included a message to alert the sure. It wouldn't be hard to change the code to track each of the matched rows instead of just the last one.

Comment: This is perfect for what I need thank you sir. One question though as I have not seen this before: What does the UCase do?

Comment: It's changing all the characters to be uppercase, that way comparison isn't case sensitive.

Comment: Perfect forward thinking

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using vlookup, as it's basically designed around your problem. It takes an input, finds it in one column, then outputs the same row in a different column. It shouldn't be difficult to make the output dependent on two vlookups matching to the same output.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/